# Why isn't IntelliJ IDEA resolving maven properties?

Tags: java, windows, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 community edition on windows 10 64-bit. It correctly imported and resolved few dependencies like spring-boot, MySQL connector Java, etc.,. However, when I try to add a new dependency for hibernate-core and import changes, it says "Cannot resolve dependency hibernate core".

The "Pom.xml":

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.resondate</groupId>
    <artifactId>resondate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>resondate</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error message that comes up is as follows:

> Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.0.0.Alpha4

It does this for all versions of hibernate-core. Please provide insights as to why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core`? The `org.hibernate:hibernate-core` dependency has a relocation to that artifact.

Comment: The problem is that https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha4/pom is a pom type and a relocation dependency which produces a warning on the console during build. And you should use org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core6.0.0.Alpha4 instead as @MarkRotteveel already has written. Furthermore usually a dependency of packaging `pom` is usually wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to change the hibernate version with Spring Boot? This is not a good idea because this version is not supported by Spring Data JPA

Comment: @khmarbaise A relocation artifact should transparently redirect to the other artifact. It shouldn't normally result in a 'Cannot resolve ....' error.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it simply can't do that ...it will produce a WARNING on command line ...and if it would transparently redirect no one would ever change it's dependencies cause it would work...Apart from being a pom packaging as a dependency is simply wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise It produces a warning _"The artifact <old-coordinates> has been relocated to <new-coordinates>"_ and then proceeds to use the artifact from the new coordinates.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't get that error.. so maybe this isn't related to relocation? Anyways, I will try out with alternate urls.

Comment: @khmarbaise it is still giving me the same error even with the orm url.

Comment: Please show the exact output....

Comment: It says **Cannot resolve org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.0.0.Alpha3** . Some more information: (can provide context)

_maven says "cannot access central in offline mode" and well I have internet access and there's no *.xml in my .m2_

Comment: There is springboot-starter-data-jpa already included which comes with hibernate-core. Not sure but suppose this have been occurred because you have to upgrade them without exclude in jpa dependancy.

Comment: For more info check this link in compile dependencies section, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.2.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use Hibernate's Alpha version.
2. If you cannot resist, instead of overriding the whole dependency block, just specify the version you want. Thanks to Spring Boot's parent pom this will work flawlessly. Example:

Instead of:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Alpha4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Do:

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.13.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

Same for all other dependencies, like mysql etc.

3. The version override to 6.0.0.Alpha won't work for Hibernate, as the actual groupId has changed, to `org.hibernate.orm` . Hence, I wouldn't do it :)

   .